# how to place angular js controller in html

Tags: angularjs

In my `angular js` application we are using `ui-router` for routing. Currently we placed all controllers are placed in external `js` files and this `js` files are included in `index.html` file, but as per performance wise application loading very slow.

If we are declaring controllers in html files showing error like undefined controller. can any one help this issue.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you please share your code snippets here

Comment: please post your code above

Comment: Looks like loading the code in the wrong order but that's really all we can tell from this.

Comment: I think inline vs external scripts is almost irrelevant if you compare to how you serve your other files  Like try using the minified versions and check files are getting cached/gzipped or use a CDN for angular/router if you can't be assed with dev-ops. I'm sure you don't want to use minified versions in development, but if we are speaking about testing the end-results, those things has to come before inlining your controllers.

Comment: the thing you are trying to do will probably result in minimal boost I would look for problems elsewhere altho it's hard to say that for certain without looking at the code. Uglification and minification will probably do you better but when I face cases of slow performance its most likely to be big resources you are using besides the code or code is of very poor quality. Typically in Angular, you might be abusing events or watches too often..

Answer (score 0):

here is the code

```
<script>
    angular.module('testApp').controller('TestCtrl1', function ($scope,$http,$stateParams) {
        $scope.test = "test sample";
    });
```

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="min-height:595px;" ng-controller="TestCtrl1">
<h1>{{test}} page</h1>
```